# ionic2 ModalController and providers

Tags: ionic2

This is how I create a modal page:

```
let signup = this.modalCtrl.create(SignupPage);
signup.present();
```

SignupPage is dependent on a service and I'm trying to inject the service in the constructor of the sign up page as usual:

```
constructor(public backendService: BackendService) { }
```

This way I'm getting a No provider for BackendService error. It seems that ModalController is not behaving along the rules for dependency injection.

What's the recommended way for passing services to modals? Should I pass the service from the presenting controller to the modal?

Comment: Looks like you trying to present modal too early and ModalController is not ready yet. Try presenting your modal later in Lifecycle events like `ionViewDidEnter` or `ionViewLoaded`

Comment: @dafyk Actually I do it in ionViewLoaded event.

Comment: Are you listing your BackendService in `@Componentn({providers:[BackendService]})` ?

Comment: @dafyk Yes, I do. Also I can use the service from other components but not from the modal component.

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit. So did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue. Can you share the correct solution for this?

Comment: @AweSIM Not yet but I didn't check the latest version of Ionic yet. What I'm doing at the moment is passing the services by parameters in the modal creation call.

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit. I managed to solve this. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045395/ionic2-using-singleton-service-in-modal-page it might help you as well..

Comment: @AweSIM Thanks for the link. I guess that wasn't available yet when I tried it because I remember creating a similar solution. Now I'm going to go back and change my code :-)