# Ionic2 :: Using singleton service in Modal page

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a service which is supposed to be a singleton and needs to be accessed from multiple views. By adding the service in the `providers` array in `app.components.ts`, I am able to access a singleton instance of the service from most pages.

However, this fails if a component is loaded as a Modal using the `ModalController`. It gives me the `No provider for XYZ` error.

What do I have to do to consume a singleton service inside a component loaded by `ModalController`?

Comment: have you tried by importing that service in that module also ?

Comment: Add it in the `providers: [XYZ]` within the `@Component`

Comment: Could you please add some code? I'm also using a singleton service from a page opened as a modal and works properly.

Comment: @PardeepJain. I have to import using `import {...} from ...` to use it obviously. But if I add it to the ModalView's `providers` array, I get `No provider for MyService`. However, I did manage to solve it. See my answer below. =)

Comment: @Ivaro18. I have tried doing that too. If I add the service to the `providers` array inside the `@Component` that will be rendered using `ModalController`, it gives me `No provider for MyService` error. The same page displayed in the default nav stack works fine. It's the ModalController that fails to resolve the service. Anyhow, I did manage to solve this issue. See my answer below. =)

Comment: @sebaferreras. I have posted the code I'm now using in my answer below. It works now. =)

Comment: @AweSIM nice , solved yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

So, I was able to make it work as follows:

**1. Create a service**

```
@Injectable() export class MyService { ... }
```

**2. Add the service in `app.module.ts` in the `providers` array**

```
providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, MyService]
```

**3. Consume the service in any `Page` or `Modal`**

```
@Component(...)
export class MyModalOrPage {
    constructor(public service: MyService) { ... }
}
```

Viola! Singleton service instance available throughout pages and modals. Works like a charm! =)

Comment: Just wondering, since you said singleton. Do the variables from this service stay on session level? Or application level? (Or Component level - which I dont hop). So basically is there a `MyService` generated per user, 1 for all users or 1 for each component that consumes it?

Comment: @Ivaro18. I believe it is one instance per user. I'm using `Ionic2` to develop an application that can be deployed on a physical device. So there's only ONE USER for the application on each device.

Comment: I did what you said but still get one instance of service for each component. Don't know how to solve it :S

Comment: Me too, maybe a bug, same code in a normal page behave as singleton, in modal page creates new instance